# Using nosql for a browser extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, nosql

I'd like to have a backend for my chrome/firefox extension app which makes queries to a local (preferably nosql) database. Is there any way to do this? Perhaps a query language for accessing chrome.storage?

Comment: Firefox has SQLite.jsm which is pretty optimized, you don't want to use that?

Answer (score 1):

read about html5 storage in particular indexedDb and web sql. those are the only possible ways to query storage (ok well the html5 filesystem api is also a way that could be considered indexed by using folders).

All three work well in chrome. Make sure to use them from the correct location (background script). Havent tried with other browsers, check their html5 compatibility.

Even if you use something specific of Chrome, both Firefox and Edge recently promissed supporting chrome extensions by just repackaging them for their store.